# SQL Group by Client Location

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, data-manipulation

Sample of Data I am trying to manipulate

```
Order  | OrderDate | ClientName| ClientAddress |  City  | State|  Zip  |
-------|-----------|-----------|---------------|--------|------|-------|
CO101  | 1/5/2015  | Client ABC| 101 Park Drive| Boston |  MA  | 02134 | 
C0102  | 2/6/2015  | Client ABC| 101 Park Drive| Boston |  MA  | 02134 | 
C0103  | 1/7/2015  | Client ABC| 354 Foo Pkwy  | Dallas |  TX  | 75001 |
C0104  | 3/7/2015  | Client ABC| 354 Foo Pkwy  | Dallas |  TX  | 75001 |
C0105  | 5/7/2015  | Client XYZ| 1 Binary Road | Austin |  TX  | 73301 | 
C0106  | 1/8/2015  | Client XYZ| 1 Binary Road | Austin |  TX  | 73301 | 
C0107  | 7/9/2015  | Client XYZ| 51 Testing Rd | Austin |  TX  | 73301 |
```

I have a database setup in MS-SQL Server with all client orders for the past two year period. Some clients only have one location, others have multiple locations. I would like to write a script that will show me the number of orders a customer placed by location over the total number of weeks there was at least one order.

Based on the results of this script, I would like to be able to deduce every customer location's summary of unique orders (placed at various times). For example:

- Client ABC has placed 45 orders over 35 total weeks at location A
- Client ABC has placed 35 orders over 15 total weeks at location B
- Client ABC has placed 15 orders over 15 total weeks at location C

I would like see this information for each unique location for each client. I am not sure how to aggregate the data in such a way. Here is where I am at with my script:

```
SELECT t1.ClientName, (SELECT DISTINCT t2.ClientAddress), COUNT(DISTINCT t2.Orders) AS TotalOrders, 

DATEPART(week, t1.OrderDate) AS Week
FROM database t1 

INNER JOIN database t2 on t1.Orders = t2.Orders

GROUP BY DATEPART(week, t1.OrderDate), t1.ClientAddress, t2.ClientAddress 

HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.SalesOrder) > 1
ORDER BY TotalOrders DESC
```

The results that I get show me the unique orders by location by week, but I'm not sure how to count the number of weeks in the way that I need; I have tried writing subqueries but I keep running into issues. I realize that in this script I am showing number of order by location by each individual week, I would like to count the total number of weeks within the time frame of where there is at least one order.

The results structure is as followed:

```
| ClientName| ClientAddress |  TotalOrders | Week |
|-----------|---------------|--------------|------|
|Client ABC |101 Park Drive |      30      |  21  | 
|Client ABC |101 Park Drive |      29      |  13  | 
|Client ABC |101 Park Drive |      28      |  10  | 
|Client XYZ |1 Binary Road  |      27      |  19  | 
|Client XYZ |1 Binary Road  |      25      |  7   | 
|Client XYZ |51 Testing Rd  |      22      |  9   |
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated; thank you in advance.

Comment: Rather convoluted query, can you post some sample data

Comment: Seems to me that counting distinct weeks, rather than grouping by weeks, should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this what you want?

```
SELECT t1.ClientName, ClientAddress, COUNT(DISTINCT t1.Orders) AS TotalOrders, 

COUNT(DISTINCT DATEPART(week, t1.OrderDate)) AS Weeks
FROM database t1     

GROUP BY t1.ClientName, t1.ClientAddress

HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.SalesOrder) > 1
ORDER BY TotalOrders DESC
```

I don't really follow why you're doing a self-join.   Seems useless to me, but I left it in, just in case, and to focus only on the change I made to get your result.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't show me the total count of weeks. I need to be able to count the total amount of orders by client location over however many total weeks they had at least one order.

I don't need the inner join, I was just trying to figure out how to get the data in the way that I need. I'm not sure if a join is necessary.

Comment: How does this not show you the total count of weeks?   what does it show you?

Comment: It shows me what the results were before with total orders and each week those orders were placed, except instead of showing me the week number for that total order count, it now just shows 1 for all rows.

Comment: oops, I thought I had taken the weeks out of the group by, but I didn't.  Try my current edit.  I also removed the self-join to make it less cluttered.

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much! I was making it more complicated than it needed to be.